# How to save history between zsh terminals?

Tags: zsh, history

I do some work in a single terminal tab:

```
> ls
> ps
```

Then I close the terminal, and open a new terminal, and run history

```
> history
    1  history
```

My .zsh file looks like this

```
setopt inc_append_history
setopt share_history
```

How can I make it preserve the history between tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

I had HISTFILE specified in my .zprofile; but I had setopt share_history in my .zshrc. I moved the HISTFILE into the .zshrc, prior to the setopt line. Now it works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have the same options and my history is shared. You can check that your zsh has those options set using `setopt`.

Also keep in mind that once you have added those `setopt` lines to your zsh you would need to source or create a new zsh session for them to take effect.